# How I can test in jest line with throw e?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

How I can test in jest error case?
This is what I do:
I don't know if exist a method how to test this.

```
it ('the fetch fails and throw an error', async () => {
      let response = {
        status: 400,
        body: 
        {
          base : "RON",
          date: "2019-08-01",
          rates: {"error": 'error'}
        }
      };
      fetch.mockReject(response)
      try {
        await fetchData();
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e).toEqual(response);
        expect(await fetchData()).rejects.toThrow(e);
      }
    });
```

This is the code:

```
 fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.exo/latest?base=RON');
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
```

Comment: you need to go into the catch even if you get a successful response?

Comment: You're right! I was doing wrong. I modified it                                
                                                                                           
 fetch.mockReject(new Error('fake error message'))
      try {
        await fetchData();
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e instanceof Error).toBeTruthy();
      }

Comment: Mine was a question, but yes, you just need to throw an error even if successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[expect.assertions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) to the rescue

```
it ('the fetch fails and throw an error', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  let response = {
    status: 400,
    body: {
      base : "RON",
      date: "2019-08-01",
      rates: {"error": 'error'}
    }
  };
  fetch.mockReject(response)
  try {
    await fetchData();
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e).toEqual(response);
  }
});
```

Test will fail once no exception is thrown. It has advantages over `expect().toThrown`:

1. you don't have to return Promise in your `it()` to make it work
2. it's easier to assert several related exceptions or sequential actions failed
3. it's easier to run partial matching over error caught(say with `expect(e).toMatchObject({})` to skip some data you don't care about in current test case)

As for disadvantages - you have to update number manually after adding new assertions

Comment: Should be used as: expect.assetions(1) instead of jest.assertions(1). Actually, is there any particular reason why you used it in that way? Just want to make sure that I am not missing something. Thanks in advance @skyboyer

Comment: right, @halbano, thank you, fixed. What do you mean under _particular reason_? If I don't put `expect.assertions(1)` and `await fetchData()` does not throws I expect, test will pass successfully. With `expect.assertions(1)` it will fail like "wow, we should break here but we haven't. It's bad". Or did you talk about something else?

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear enough. My thought was "maybe can be used as jest.assertion?", but as far as you corrected it I can infer that was just a mistake.

Comment: yes, agree with you, there are different places that looks all suitable to keep this in. but this way all the checks that may make test fail are gathered under `expect` so we don't have to remember few different sources of such a checks ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ probably, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the following way:

```
async function throws () {
  throw new Error('error')
}

test('promise throws', async () => {
  await expect(throws()).rejects.toThrow()
})

test('the fetch fails with an error', async () => {
  await expect(throws()).rejects.toThrow('error');
});

test('the fetch fails with an error', () => {
  return expect(throws()).rejects.toMatch('error');
});
```

Read more [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#resolves-rejects).